# MYSQL Finding accounts that have not had log entries updated in n days

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have an SQL query that I need help with...

Basically I have two tables I need to work with. One contains customer accounts and the other contains a log of customer service reps interactions with customers. I want this query give me the id of any account that has not had a log entry (interaction) in the last 14 days. I also want to filter out a few rep accounts that are irrelevant (using the `assignedto` field as you will see). Also, the date format in the log table is funky non-standard and I cannot change it, as software I have not written also utilizes this database.

The two tables are `cm.dbs (customer accounts)` and `cm.log (interaction log)`.

This is the query I came up with but it takes **FOREVER** to run. The subquery works perfectly and takes a fraction of a second, but when the main query runs with the subquery it is just impossibly slow. I'm guessing this is because the subquery is being run for every row in the main query (and it doesn't need to be) but I am kind of clueless as to how to fix this, as I am not an expert in SQL, I know enough to create basic to intermediate queries and this is not something I have done before.

Here is the query I created so far:

```
    SELECT id FROM cm.dbs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT filenumber FROM cm.log 
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(logdate, '%m/%d/%Y') 
   BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
   AND NOW() 
   GROUP BY filenumber) 
   AND assignedto != 'OLD_ACCTS' 
   AND assignedto != 'HOUSE_ACCOUNTS' 
   AND assignedto != 'PAID_ACCOUNTS';
```

The subquery finds all the accounts that have entries in the log table within the last two weeks. It does this job perfectly. The trick is then to get the main query to find all the accounts that do not have entries.

Note also, that the `filenumber` field in cm.log corresponds to `id` in the `cm.dbs` table.

I may have approached this in a completely silly way and I am not above admitting that. Any input on making this work correctly and efficiently is appreciated. I'd also love the fixes/changes anyone recommends explained. I am not simply wanting a query built for me, I want to learn what I did wrong and how to do it better so next time I can figure this out for myself. I rarely ever ask questions like this, I usually figure things out on my own but this has me stumped.

EDIT: Here is a partial schema for the relevant fields in the tables:

cm.dbs:

```
id  int(10) UN PK AI

title   varchar(45) 

firstname   varchar(200) 

middlename  varchar(200) 

lastname    varchar(200) 

fullname    varchar(200) 

address varchar(200) 

address2    varchar(200) 

city    varchar(200) 

state   varchar(200) 

zip varchar(50) 

assignedto  varchar(200) 

...
```

cm.log:

```
id  int(10) UN PK AI

filenumber  varchar(200) 

agentname   varchar(200) 

logtime varchar(200) 

logdateandtime  varchar(200) 

logdate varchar(200) 

logmessage  mediumtext
```

Comment: Can you provide schema for those two tables involved in query. How many records does both the table holds?

Comment: The cm.dbs table literally has over 100 fields so I'm not sure if posting all that is productive but I will if you feel it is necessary. If you're wondering what kind of indexes, keys and such there, there are none. This is a database created by a third party and it is really, really poorly written. How poorly? Well, that funky date field? It's a VARCHAR(200). WHY!!!??

Comment: one optimization would be to convert that `logdate` field to native type - you're forcing mysql to convert that string to a date value for EVERY record in the table. that prevents use of indexes and forces a full-table scan every time.

Comment: I agree Marc, but I cannot change that for reasons already explained. That particular query only takes about 20 ms anyway, and the data that it puts out is the same for every row in the main query. The goal here is to somehow eliminate running the subquery for all 100,000+ rows in the cm.dbs table. There are also well over a million rows in the cm.log table and it grows by a few thousand a day.

Comment: Kelli, try getting `explain plan` of the said query and see exactly which part is taking more time. I will go with what @Marc said, I think that part is taking more time.

Comment: Did you get a chance to run the query I suggested?

Comment: Here is the output of EXPLAIN (from MYSQL WORKBENCH):

'1', 'PRIMARY', 'dbs', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '89533', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'log', 'index', NULL, 'Index_2', '203', NULL, '6', 'Using where'

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do without a database schema, but should hopefully be pretty close to what you were looking for (or at least point you in the right direction):

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbs.id
FROM cm.dbs, cm.log
WHERE dbs.id = log.filenumber
      AND STR_TO_DATE(log.logdate, '%m/%d/%Y') NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
      AND dbs.assignedto NOT IN ('OLD_ACCTS','HOUSE_ACCOUNTS','PAID_ACCOUNTS');
```

If you get a chance run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on your query and add the output to your question, so we can profile it better (and include the database schema).

Comment: I just did, and it took .8 seconds to run. Looking at the data now to see if it's correct. (Not that I doubt you :)

Comment: This query gets the records that are within 2 weeks, not the records that have no entries in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: You are correct, I missed that while refactoring the query. Fixed now (hopefully).

Comment: This seems to work quite nicely. Query runs in under 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help. After looking over the code I understand how it works as well.

Comment: Well dang... After rigorous testing I find that this isn't working either. I am still at a loss. This query still allows accounts that have log entries older than 14 days and newer than 14 days to slip through.

Comment: The problem is that this query will return filenumbers that have log entries that are newer than 14 days, as long as they also have entries older than 14 days. My original idea of selecting any and all filenumbers that have entries newer than 14 days and then eliminating those from the list is the way to go. The problem is, it just takes too long to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct to me except the change below ( since you have multiple `assignedto` values to be checked for, use a `IN` operator instead making them in separate `OR` exclusively.)

```
SELECT id FROM cm.dbs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT filenumber FROM cm.log 
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(logdate, '%m/%d/%Y') 
   BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
   AND NOW() 
   GROUP BY filenumber) 
   AND assignedto NOT IN ('OLD_ACCTS','HOUSE_ACCOUNTS','PAID_ACCOUNTS');
```

Comment: Makes complete sense regarding using NOT IN for the accounts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are attacking this in the wrong way. Lets break down what you're looking for.

First thing is the filenumber and max logdate:

```
SELECT filenumber, MAX(logdate)
FROM cm.log
GROUP BY filenumber
```

So now we just need to join it to the other table:

```
SELECT filenumber, MAX(logdate), assignedto
FROM cm.log as log
INNER JOIN cm.dbs as dbs ON log.filenumber = dbs.id
GROUP BY filenumber
```

Now we want to apply some conditions on what we just selected (older than 2 weeks, not in those 3 groups) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT log.filenumber, MAX(logdate) as logdate, assignedto
    FROM cm.log as log
    INNER JOIN cm.dbs as dbs ON log.filenumber = dbs.id 
    GROUP BY filenumber) t
WHERE logdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
AND assignedto NOT IN ('OLD_ACCTS','HOUSE_ACCOUNTS','PAID_ACCOUNTS')
```

Comment: I tried running this in MYSQL Workbench and got a query interrupted error. Not sure why and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I was able to get this to run by modifying it a bit, but it has the same problem as the other query I thought worked; it does not weed out filenumbers that have log entries that are newer and older than 14 days. If an account has an entry that is older than 14 days and one that is newer, it will include it. That isn't going to work.

Comment: The above code should only return filenumbers where the MAX (most recent) logdate is older than 14 days.

Comment: >sigh< I need to walk away from this... For like the next two months.

Getting "Every derived table must have its own alias" error.

Comment: Wait don't walk away yet! You are right, there were some errors in there because I hand coded it. Now it has a group by and an alias. Here it is working:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4187d/5

Comment: OK... I appreciate your effort. I've never had this much problem trying to get a freakin' query to work correctly. But now I'm getting Error 1052: Column 'filenumber' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Do you have a `filenumber` in both tables??  Regardless, if necessary change `filenumber`  to `log.filenumber` to remove ambiguity

Comment: Yes, but filenumber in log corresponds to id in dbs. The filenumber field in dbs is something completely different. I hate this database.

Comment: Looks like it may have worked. I had to add STR_TO_DATE(logdate, '%m/%d/%Y') to convert that stupid string date format but other than that it ran and returned over 26,000 rows. Thank you. I feel really stupid that I haven't been able to get this to work on my own. Let me look at the data and get back to you on whether it worked or not :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does have the same issue as the other query. It does not weed out accounts that have log entries newer than 14 days, if they also have a log entry that is older than 14 days. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I think I am going to have to come up with a solution that uses multiple SQL queries and some processing/storing of data in arrays by PHP to make this work correctly. Pure MYSQL just isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Did you see my sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4187d/5  id 1 has log entries newer than 14 days,and also older than 14 days. It gets properly removed from the resultset. Feel free to add more test data and try it. You may have some other weird data issue.

Comment: I did see it and I agree. I have figured out that for some reason, MYSQL is not comparing the converted date properly. When I figure out why, I will post my results. At this point I'm almost thinking it's a bug, but it's such a glaring one that I don't see how it could have gone unnoticed.

Comment: Yes, those can be tricky. Take your STR_TO_DATE() values and put them back through DATE_FORMAT() and make sure you end up with date you think you do. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date